# Is a ball-end the default end for a violin string?

Tags: strings, violin

When buying violin strings I am often confused about what end the string has. For the E string it usually says ball-end or loop end, but often the other strings do not mention the end explicitely. Can I assume that ball-end is implicit?

Comment: Can you...finish the question, please...!

Comment: When in doubt, just call or email the store you're buying from.

Comment: As User Tim puts it: "Can you...finish the question, please...!"

Comment: Sorry, don't know why the question was cut short. It should be fixed now :-)

Comment: btw- if it comes up, a ball end can be converted to a loop end by merely pushing the ball out of the loop.

Comment: Thanks, my problem is the other way around. I need the ball :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the type of strings.

For steel or synthetic core, the three lower strings are always ball end, and you can get three different types of ends for the E: ball end, loop end, or removable ball end (take the ball out and you get a loop end).

But gut strings are available in either ball end or loop end for all strings - some manufacturers offer only one, some give you a choice.

Comment: Exactly.  The modern trend is toward ball ends for all strings.